# iptable-like forwarding in Windows

Tags: windows, forwarding

Is there any way to implement routing/forwarding based on information differ from an destination IP in the Windows environment ? I mean that in Linux using iptables/tc/iproute2 I can define a policy of choosing an outgoing interface for forwarding a traffic based on destination port, ToS/DSCP, time-of-day, rate any combination of various parameters etc.

Neither Winsock nor Routing Table Manager (RTMv2) APIs in Windows seem to provide similar flexibility

Any idea/direction/suggestion ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check out netsh:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730801(WS.10).aspx

Comment: PowerShell should also work by means of WMI.